# Unable to Find Field Rails TDD

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, guard

I'm following along with this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had/ and I am having an issue. I created this form under views/tasks/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Task.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :task %>
    <%= f.text_field :task %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then in spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb I have

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe TasksController do

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      @task = Task.create :task => 'go to bed'

      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "creates a new task" do
        visit tasks_path
        fill_in 'Task', :with => 'go to work'
        click_button 'Create Task'

        current_path.should == tasks_path
        page.should have_content 'go to work'
        save_and_open_page
    end
end

end
```

When I run that with Guard, I get this failure:

```
Failures:

  1) TasksController GET 'index' creates a new task
     Failure/Error: fill_in 'Task', :with => 'go to work'
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Task"
     # ./spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I think, you're creating the view and controller code in a single file.

Comment: What do you mean by that? they're in seperate files as I said.

Comment: Not sure why that's not working, but compared with the tutorial source, you should have that form using a controller instance variable `@task` instead of `Task.new`

Comment: What I meant is, you're describing `TaskController`'s job, but 2nd half of the code, you are calling `visit`, `click`, `fill_in` which are the view part. You have to create 2 different rSpec to test them

Comment: How would I do that? (Sorry, I'm very new at this)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but are those supposed to be "if" statements in your controller? Because you wrote them as "it".

Comment: Changing to "if" seems to make it worse. According to the tutorial, it should be "it".

Comment: That's a spec, not a controller, so it's using rspec-style "describe-it" syntax

Comment: Doh! Sorry, was in a hurry. Should've given it more attention. My apologies!